# getting the type that called the super constructor

Tags: dart

If a class that is extended by other classes

```
class x{
  x(){
    Type calledByClass = ??
  }
}

class y extends x{
  y:super();
}

class z extends x{
  z:super();
}
```

using mirrors, is it possible inside the constructor of x to get the type from which the super constructor was called?

for example `new z()` will initialize `calledByClass` to type z

note that my super constructor can't have parameters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
void main() {
  new x();
  new y();
  new z();
}

class x {
  x() {
    Type calledByClass = this.runtimeType;
    print("calledByClass: $calledByClass");
  }
}

class y extends x {
  y() : super();
}

class z extends x {
  z() : super();
}
```

Output:

`calledByClass: x
    calledByClass: y
    calledByClass: z`

**Harder to determine the superclass.**

Eg.

```
for example new z() will initialize superClass to type x
```